# Ensure Relative Path is Used in cmd.exe when Running Batch Files From Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, batch-file

I have an Excel file with a button that calls a Shell command in VB:

```
Shell(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\python_script.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

The Shell command calls the above batch file that runs a Python script:

```
python python_script.py
```

All the pertinent files (the Excel file, the batch file, the data files, the Python file) are all located in the same directory, call this `sample_program`, because I am building this for someone else and I intend for them to simply unzip it and run it.

In Excel, when testing this, I click the button and then get this error:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents>python python_script.py
python: can't open file 'python_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

For some reason, although all these files are in the same location, the cmd.exe is running from my user directory: `C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents`

I don't want cmd.exe to use this path; I want it to use the `path\to\sample_program` directory.

How do I get this to use relative paths so when I transfer this folder to someone else, and they place it anywhere, it will work as a self-contained unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if `path\to\sample_program` is on the same drive as your home drive

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "&&python_script.bat"
```

or this if `path\to\sample_program` is *not* on the same drive as your home drive, or you dont know in advance

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k " & Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 2) & "&&cd " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "&&python_script.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environ("username")` to get the user logon name, so for your sample (which I presume is Windows 7)

```
Sub GetDir()
MsgBox "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents"
End Sub
```

You can also automatically retrieve certain locations regardless of OS using SpecialFOlders, ie

```
Sub GetPath()
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Documents = wshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
MsgBox Documents
End Sub
```

Comment: Will this work if the folder I give to my user is located here: `D:\testing\scripts\today` for example?  I think I'm trying to make it so the `cmd.exe` doesn't use the user's Documents directory but instead uses the path where all the files are located.

Comment: Does you code create the directory, and then copy all the relevant files to it? From your question I had assumed that the files would deployed over a network, hence the need for a relative path

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer... No, the files are manually added to a directory on my local machine.  I intend to package them into a ZIP file and then send to someone.  Then the recipient would unzip and run from wherever the unzipped directory is at.  In this case, the files would need to run with the root of the unzipped folder as the root of the application.